# Setting inner html with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, dom

Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnView").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Default.aspx/getImages",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{'chk1' : '" + document.getElementById('chk1').checked + "','chk2' : '" + document.getElementById('chk2').checked + "','chk3' : '" + document.getElementById('chk3').checked + "','chk4' : '" + document.getElementById('chk4').checked + "','chk5' : '" + document.getElementById('chk5').checked + "','chk6' : '" + document.getElementById('chk6').checked + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#imagesDiv").html(data.d);
                    alert($("#imagesDiv").html());
                }
            });
            alert("BEFORE RETURN");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

i can see the html in the first alert, but not on the page or the page source???
any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just needed to add return false inside the success function as below:

```
success: function (data) {
                $("#imagesDiv").html(data.d);
                return false;
            }
```